# yosemite with safari beachball

Tags: safari, macos

When I click on a link while in Safari - or put a query into the search I repeatedly get the beachball - this doesn't happen with Firefox or Chrome. What can I do?

Comment: I get lots of beachballs on safari - and red safari processes in Activity Monitor. Quitting Safari fixes it for a while then it starts again.

Comment: I have just switched to Chrome in Yosemite - very fast, none of the same issues. I think this must be a huge issue - I have a 2014 MacBook Air 11". Safari looks hugely flawed - why isn't this getting more coverage?